# Show $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))\cong C_3 \times C_3$ with $L$ splitting field of $X^6+3X^3+3$

Tags: permutations, galois-theory

Given the splitting field $L$ of $f(X)=X^6+3X^3+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\omega$ be a third primitive root of unity, so $\omega^3=1, \omega\neq 1$. Suppose $\omega^k\alpha,\omega^l\sqrt[3]{3}/\alpha\in L$, with $l,k\in\{0,1,2\}$ are the six zeros of $f$. Then I proved that $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt[3]{3})$.

I know $\alpha^3\in\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.

Let $\sqrt[3]{3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Show $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))\cong C_3 \times C_3$.

My reader starts by picking $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))$. It then concludes that there are $k,l\in\{0,1,2\}$ such that $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{3})=\omega^k\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sigma(\alpha)=\omega^l\alpha$. Which are nine possibilities.

I know that elements of $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))$ permute zeros of $f$, **but why in this way?** Why can't we have $\sigma(\alpha)=\omega^k\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{3})=\omega^l\alpha$.

It then concludes that those nine possibilities are all elements of $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))$ since $[L:\mathbb{Q}(\omega)]=9$. **But I thought** $[L : \mathbb{Q}]=[L:\mathbb{Q}(\omega)][\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]$. I have previously proven that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=18$. But then, to get to the 9, we must have $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. But I thought that the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ would be $X^3-1$, because then $\omega^3-1=1-1=0$, which would mean that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=3\neq 2$.

Comment: $\omega^2+\omega+1=\dfrac{\omega^3-1}{\omega-1}=0$ so indeed $[\mathbb Q(\omega):\mathbb Q]=2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Does this type of equation extend to other roots of unity?

Comment: If $\zeta^n=1$ and $\zeta\ne1$ then $\dfrac{\zeta^n-1}{\zeta-1}=\zeta^{n-1}+...\zeta^2+\zeta+1=0$

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $X^6+3X^3+3=0$ then $\alpha \mapsto \sqrt[3]{3}$ is not an automorphism because  $ \sqrt[3]{3}^6+3  \sqrt[3]{3}^3+3\ne0;$ $ \sqrt[3]{3}$ is not a zero of $X^6+3X^3+3$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner O wow, that clears up a lot for me. So elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ are mapped to itself. Roots are permuted, and other elements can do what they want as long as they go by the rules of automorphisms, e.g. $\sigma(a^2)=\sigma(a)\sigma(a)$?

Comment: It need not be the case that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]=(n-1)$, for instance take $\zeta_4=i$, but $\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}$ has degree 2. It is always the case though that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p):\mathbb{Q}]=(p-1)$, for *prime p*. In general, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$ has degree φ(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $X^6+3X^3+3$, then so are $\omega\alpha, \omega^2\alpha , \sqrt[3]3/\alpha, \omega\sqrt[3]3/\alpha, $ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]3/\alpha,$ where $\omega^3=1$ but $\omega\ne1$, i.e., $\dfrac{\omega^3-1}{\omega-1}=\omega^2+\omega+1=0.\;$  ($\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.)

The map you suggested, which takes $\alpha$ to $\sqrt[3]3$, is not an automorphism,

because $\alpha$ is a root of $X^6+3X^3+3$, but $\sqrt[3]3$ is not.

Finally, as indicated, the minimal polynomial for $\omega$ is a quadratic, so indeed $[\mathbb Q(\omega):\mathbb Q]=2$.

Comment: Hmm I see. But I have difficulty confirming automorphisms. When we have $L/\mathbb{Q}$ a splitting field of $X^3-2$, my book says that there is an automorphism that maps $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ to $\omega^2$. But that is not a ring homomorphism under addition right? Since $\sigma(\omega+\omega)=4\omega^2$, but $\sigma(\omega)+\sigma(\omega)=2\omega^2$.

Comment: Automorphism that maps $w$ to $w^2$ maps ($2$ to $2$ and) $2w$ to $2w^2$